# How to create a unique identifier for a Vue JS 2 App

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, uuid

I'm wondering if there is a nice way to have a UUID for a Vue JS 2 App.

I'm currently developing a Laravel API that is consumed by Android/IOS devices that identifies themselves by using the installation_id. Since it only changes on new app installation, it seems like the best approach for this purpose.

Now I have to develop the Vue JS app, but of course, there is no such thing. I've found this package but unfortunately, it only supports Vue JS 3: https://github.com/VitorLuizC/vue-uuid

Basically, what I need is to have `uuid` **per app instance** which persist on page refresh and even of hard refresh (not sure if possible at all) meaning clearing the app data from localStorage.

So far, I can only imagine creating a random `uuid` using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) and storing it on localStorage, then on app mount check if this `uuid` exists on localStorage and if not, store it, otherwise just continue on.

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'
...
new Vue({
    router,
    mounted () {
        if (!localStorage.getItem('installation_id')) {
            localStorage.setItem('installation_id', uuidv4())
        }
    }
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

I will appreciate any help to get the right path to achieve this.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable approach. Why not go with that? And `vue-uuid` is just a "convenience lib" that exposes `uuid` as Vue global property...not worth using this lib.

Comment: Yeah saving to localStorage is a very reasonable approach. If you need to really save it per user account then you would need to save it to the user's table in the data base and request it on page refresh.

Comment: Yes, I think that using localStorage will be enough. The main purpose is for sending WebSocket/FCM/APN notifications. Since an authenticated user can use multiple devices at the same time, I'm maintaining a devices DB table with all user UUID. Said that I don't see any viable way to clear localStorage without considering the new Vue instance a new device. In that case, the device record pointing to an old/non-existent Vue instance will be sending notifications to nobody,